# link_to populated with what was entered in text_field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

How to pass with `link_to` whatever was entered into `text_field`?

**new.html.erb**

```
<%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control', id: "challenge-action-home",maxlength: @maximum_length, placeholder: 'Enter Challenge' %>
<%= link_to create_challenge_path(challenge: {name: ???}), data: { modal: true } do %>
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
<% end %>

<script>
  # Maybe use javascript?
</script>
```

For example, a user may enter "Run 5 Miles" into the `text_field`. How to pass with `link_to`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!

```
<%= f.text_field :name, class: "name_field", id: "challenge-name", maxlength: @maximum_length, placeholder: 'Enter Challenge' %>

<%= link_to "Save", create_challenge_path(challenge: {name: @challenge.name}), data: { modal: true }, class: "create_challenge_link" %>

<script>
  $(".create_challenge_link").click(function() {
    $(this).attr("href", function() {
      return this.href + $('.name_field').val();
    });
  });
</script>
```